# Is there an easy way to programmatically extract IP address?

Tags: shell, networking, ip

Is there an easy way to programmatically extract IP address, without tedious parsing of `ifconfig`?  I would not mind simple command output processing using `sed` to do it but not processing multiline files from `/etc` some place.  What I am trying to do is modify my `.bashrc` to display the IP address of the host in the greeting message.  I am using `Ubuntu 12.04` but decided to post here instead of the Ubuntu forum because I consider this to be not distro-specific.

Comment: hosts have IP (v4 or v6) addresses on each of the IP networks they're connected to. For instance, most host have a `127.0.0.1` IPv4 address and a `::1` IPv6 interface on the loopback _network_. Which one do you want to find?

Comment: the one in the `eth0` section on `ifconfig` that is labeled `inet addr:`

Comment: I assume you want your private address, not your public one?

Comment: yes, @strugee, that is correct

Answer (score 57, accepted):

#### NOTES

1. NIC device handles

   The examples below assume that the network interface is a wireless card named `wlan0`. Adjust this bit in the examples for your particular situation. For example if it's a wired NIC card, then it's likely `eth0`.
2. IPv4 - (Internet Protocol version 4)

   Also these examples are returning the IPv4 address. the "dotted quad" that most people identify as their "IP Address".

   For example:

   ```
   inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   ```
3. IPv6 - (Internet Protocol version 6)

   If your system is configured to support IPv6 you'll see both the "dotted quad" as well as the IPv6 IP addresses in the `ifconfig` output.

   For example:

   ```
   inet6 addr: fe80::226:c7ff:fe85:a720/64 Scope:Link
   ```

   The commands below explicitly ignore this, but could be adapted quite easily to grab this information instead.

#### Solutions (using `ifconfig`)

There are many ways to do this. You could for example use this `awk` script to parse out the IP address of your wireless LAN NIC (wlan0):

```
$ ifconfig wlan0 | grep "inet " | awk -F'[: ]+' '{ print $4 }'
192.168.1.20
```

You can do this and make it more compact:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/t addr:/{gsub(/.*:/,"",$2);print$2}'
192.168.1.20
```

You could also do it using `perl`:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0 | perl -nle'/t addr:(\S+)/&&print$1'
192.168.1.20
```

The Perl example is about as compact as it can get.

There are countless other ways to do this, these are just a couple of examples to get you started.

#### EDIT #1

Some additional notes and comments. @StephaneChazelas demonstrated that there is an even more compact version using `grep`:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0|grep -Po 't addr:\K[\d.]+'
192.168.1.20
```

This solution makes use of `grep`'s ability in newer versions to make use of PCRE (Perl regular expressions), along with it's `-o` switch to return just what matches the regular expression.

#### Solutions (using `ip`)

As was also mentioned in the comments, `ifconfig` can be troublesome to use on systems that have multiple IP addresses assigned to a network device, given it only returns the first one. So it's better to use the command `ip` in these situations.

For example:

```
$ ip addr show wlan0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'
192.168.1.20
```

You can also tell `ip` to only show you IPv4 information for a given network interface. In this case we're looking only at the interface named `wlan0`:

```
$ ip -f inet addr show wlan0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'
192.168.1.20
```

#### References

- [Golfing the Extraction of IP Addresses from ifconfig](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/golfing-the-extraction-of-ip-addresses-from-ifconfig/)
- [ip man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)
- [ifconfig man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig)
- [PCRE man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcre)
- [grep man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

Comment: PERFECT !!  I just replaced your `wlan0` with `eth0` and got the IP address

Comment: @amphibient - glad to hear it solved your problem. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Note that it returns the _first_ IPv4 address of the interface. Interfaces can have more than one IP address. You need `ip addr show` to see all of them as `ifconfig` only shows one of them.

Comment: Shorter with GNU `grep`: `ifconfig eth0|grep -Po 't addr:\K[\d.]+'` which has the advantage of returning a non-zero exit status if the interface has no address.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - remind me to never play golf with you 8-)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: It does depend on system configuration, but on most of my machines `hostname -i` works quite well.

Comment: @user1129682 - yeah that only works if the hostname the system is set to can resolve via DNS to an IP address.

Comment: On Raspberry Pi this works: `ifconfig wlan0 | grep "inet " | awk -F'[: ]+' '{ print $3 }'` , it's `3` and not 4 for rpi.

Comment: `ip a | grep eth1 |  awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -d '/' -f1 | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 31):

`$ hostname -I`

For example:

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.1.18
```

Info. from manpages:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/hostname.1.html
    http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hostname

Comment: "Invalid option" - the only flag available in `man hostname` for an IP address is `i` and that only returns the local loop...

Comment: You must be using a very very old version of **hostname** or have some kind of problem. In all new **ubuntus** that I have tried, and maybe olders too, it works perfectly well.

Comment: @mattdm: It is so clear that it needs no explanation It is clearer than all above explanations

Comment: `SYNOPSIS

       hostname  [-v] [-a|--alias] [-d|--domain] [-f|--fqdn|--long] [-A|--all-
       fqdns]    [-i|--ip-address]    [-I|--all-ip-addresses]     [-s|--short]
       [-y|--yp|--nis]
       hostname [-v] [-b|--boot] [-F|--file filename] [hostname]
       hostname [-v] [-h|--help] [-V|--version]`

Comment: `-I, --all-ip-addresses
              Display  all  network  addresses  of  the  host.   This   option
              enumerates  all  configured addresses on all network interfaces.
              The  loopback  interface  and  IPv6  link-local  addresses   are
              omitted.  Contrary  to option -i, this option does not depend on
              name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about the order  of
              the output.` That is why it works.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/hostname.1.html
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/hostname.1.html
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hostname
old:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/hostname.1.html

Comment: Ubuntu is one flavour of Linux: you should never assume it is the default...

Comment: Do not run this command on a Solaris host unless you want the hostname to be changed to `-I`.

Comment: beats the pants off the other solutions

Answer (score 11):

Here is another one using "ip" but this works better when your device might be connected with different interfaces, such as wired Ethernet sometimes and WiFi other times. I also used "sed" instead of "grep" or "perl", for variety.

This finds whatever source IP has a route to the Internet. Or to Google's DNS at any rate.

```
ip -o route get 8.8.8.8 | sed -e 's/^.* src \([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/'
```

Comment: A bit silly yet effective way: `ip -o route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -F'src | uid' '{print $2}'`

Comment: Slightly briefer: `ip -o route get 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP '(?<=src )\S+'`

Comment: Even briefer, but probably not as robust: ```cut -d' ' -f7 < <(ip -o route get 8.8.8.8)```

Comment: If you have a recent `iproute2` (with json output) and the `jq` tool installed, this is a nice variant requiring no pattern-matching (to be a little more future-proof): `ip -j route get 8.8.8.8 | jq -r '.[0].prefsrc'`

Comment: ...and here is a version if you are in Bash shell and don't want to rely on any other executable than `ip`: `ip="$(ip -j route get 8.8.8.8)"; ip="${ip##*\"prefsrc\":\"}"; ip="${ip%%\"*}"`