# iproute2 get inet for interface

Tags: iproute, ip-address

#### Things I tried:

- `scope inet` gives `Error: argument "inet" is wrong: invalid "scope"`
- `to inet` gives `Error: ??? prefix is expected rather than "inet".`
- (flag) `inet` gives `Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "inet" is a garbage.`
- `label inet` gives no output
- List item

And thats exhausted my ideas. Is there even a built in way to get interface properties without a nasty grep 🙳 grok pipeline?

### How Can I Get My Interface's IP (inet) Address?

How can I get the ipv4 (inet) field alone directly from the iproute2 tools `ip` command?

I was trying to the effect of:

```
ip address show dev docker0 [magical argument here]
```

But I dont think I really understand the options here:

> ```
>        ip address show [ dev IFNAME ] [ scope SCOPE-ID ]
>                            [ to PREFIX ] [ FLAG-LIST ] [ label LABEL ] [up]
> ```
>
> — $ ip address show help

---

Comment: As far as I know, the most "concise" output for address is returned with `ip a show dev $INTERFACE`

Comment: @ILMostro_7 If I was unclear, I want just the inet value, nothing more in the output.

Comment: Use `grep`, `awk`, `perl` or whatever you like to extract the ip address proper from the output. Keep in mind that interfaces can have multiple ip addresses.

Comment: @dirkt Sorry if this is unclear, this question is asking how to get the value specifically, and directly from iproute2, without using a shell pipeline to parse any output.

Comment: Then the answer is "you can't".

Comment: The tool really needs a way to write custom format expressions so you can easily output what you need. Or dump json. Or something.

Answer (score 3):

see [Is there an easy way to programmatically extract IP address?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87468/is-there-an-easy-way-to-programmatically-extract-ip-address)

```
$ ip -f inet addr show wlan0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'
192.168.1.20
```