# Putting external IP into a variable - grep operation failed

Tags: security, ip, variable, web, ifconfig

I need to put the IP of my VPS machine into a variable. I mean to the external IP address appearing the value of `inet addr` section, in `ifconfig` output.

I've tried:

```
ipa="$(hostname -i)"
```

But `echo ${ipa}` brought the localhost token: `127.0.1.1`, so I looked for other solutions and all I found includes many pipes and `awk` operations which I know nothing about (never used `awk` and I'm not very familiar with regex).

I tried this:

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep "inet addr:[0-999]\.[0-999]\.[0-999]\.[0-999]")
```

But it failed given that `echo ${ipa}` has an empty line of output.

Why did what I've tried failed or at least how would you solve it?

Comment: It is most important for me to understand what why I tried failed (please review my question edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | perl -lane '/inet addr:(\S+)/ and $1 !~ "^127" and print $1')
```

Also see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87470/265461) for a plethora of alternatives.
E.g. using `grep`:

```
ipa=$(ifconfig | grep -Po 'inet addr:\K[^\s]+' | grep -v '^127')
```

**Explanation:**

`ipa=$( )` assign the output of the command in parentheses to the variable `ipa`
`ifconfig` show interfaces and their addresses. You might prefer `ip address`
`| grep -Po 'inet addr:\K[^\s]+'` filter output using a `perl`-compatible regex, print the matched text
`| grep -v '^127'` filter again, this time excluding (`-v`) values that start (`^`) with `127`

---

To get my external ip, I usually do:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Comment: So sad I don't know `perl` so at the moment feel uncomfortable to use it (I don't want to use something I don't understand well enough, usually). What do you think on my approach?

Comment: @Benia This `perl` code is quite simple, but if you feel uncomfortable then by all means don't use it! Or learn `perl`! Or pick any of the several methods from the linked answers. I added a `grep` alternative, since you already tried with `grep`.

Comment: I've tried my example only now with `echo` in the end but the output line is empty --- my `grep` failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "inet addr:[0-999]\.[0-999]\.[0-999]\.[0-999]"
```

That would match the string `inet addr:` followed by a single character that is a digit from `0` to `9`, or a `9`, or a `9`, followed by a dot, then another character that is `0` to `9` or `9` or `9`... e.g. `inet addr:1.2.3.4`, but not `inet addr:11.22.33.44`.

Bracket groups don't match strings that form numbers, just single characters.

Comment: Additionally, even if it worked, it's going to return the entire line, containing `inet addr: .......` not just the IP address.

Comment: @EightBitTony this is because I didn't wrap the bracket gripus in parenthesis?